# Can't use manifest placeholders to remove a permission

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

I'm trying to use a manifest placeholder to remove a `uses-permission` node in the `AndroidManifest.xml` for release builds with no luck.

*build.gradle*

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        manifestPlaceholders.excludeDebugPermissions = "remove"
    }
    debug {
        manifestPlaceholders.excludeDebugPermissions = "merge"
    }
}
```

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"
    tools:node="${excludeDebugPermissions}" />
```

It produces an error like this:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   No enum constant com.android.manifmerger.NodeOperationType.${EXCLUDE_DEBUG_PERMISSIONS}

But using the placeholder anywhere else works properly (the merged manifest is OK and there is no error), e.g.

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="${excludeDebugPermissions}"
    tools:node="remove" />
```

So I suppose the `tools:node` attribute doesn't support manifest placeholders and I'm probably going to hack it by substituting the permission name instead of the node marker (`merge` / `remove`), but I would prefer to avoid it if possible.

Any advices?

Comment: are you aiming to have different permissions for debug and release builds? You can put another android manifest in src/debug. The downside is you have two to maintain.

Comment: @RobVoisey Actually I'm trying to get rid of the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission inherited from React Native.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest and cleanest way I found to solve this problem was to create a release-only AndroidManifest file (`app/src/release/AndroidManifest.xml`) with the following contents to remove the `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" tools:node="remove"/>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment about react native, I found this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5886

The solution was to have this in your build types which is slightly different to what you current have:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        manifestPlaceholders = [excludeSystemAlertWindowPermission: "false"]
    }
    release {
        manifestPlaceholders = [excludeSystemAlertWindowPermission: "true"]
    }
}
```

So this would be in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" tools:remove="${excludeSystemAlertWindowPermission}"/>
```

Comment: I have already seen that issue. The proposed solution doesn't work (confirmed [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5886#issuecomment-230569276)) and I don't understand why it could as the [doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html) clearly says that `tools:remove` will "remove the specified attributes" and it accepts attribute names, not a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the Android flavor approach, here is my solution to allow a different permission setup for a specific purpose for my app manifest.

For example, I can optionally enable/disable the ***Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE*** permission if I set my custom **USE_PERMISSION_BUILD_SERIAL** flag in my `build.gradle` as follows:

```
ext {
    //to enable READ_PHONE_STATE permission to access Build.SERIAL used 
    //for our bug reporting feature. 
    //Since there is a privacy concern with Build.SERIAL, we can decide 
    //to allow/disallow it right here!
    //If it is disabled, the Phone permission will not appear at all.
    //If it is enabled, the user will decide instead to allow the Phone 
    //access during its permission request as usual
    USE_PERMISSION_BUILD_SERIAL = true
    
    // whatever the rest...
}

android {

    defaultConfig {
    
        buildConfigField("boolean", "USE_PERMISSION_BUILD_SERIAL", "${USE_PERMISSION_BUILD_SERIAL}")
    }

    sourceSets {
    
        main {
            if (USE_PERMISSION_BUILD_SERIAL) {
                manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifestBuild.xml'
            }
            else {
                manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            }
        }
    }           
}
```

Next, I prepare two different manifest files, `AndroidManifestBuild.xml` and `AndroidManifest.xml`, and store them under the `src/main` folder of my project.

Unlike the normal `AndroidManifest.xml`, I will request for the ***Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE*** permission in the `AndroidManifestBuild.xml` file as follows:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.app">

    <!-- required for accessing android.os.Build.getSerial() in Android 9.0+ -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    
</manifest>
```

Don't worry about the manifest name, as Gradle will build the final manifest file with the correct name for our Android application.

Using Gradle's *buildConfigField()* feature, I can use the `BuildConfig.USE_PERMISSION_BUILD_SERIAL` which stores the state of **USE_PERMISSION_BUILD_SERIAL** flag in my code to prepare the necessary permission request optionally.